# Confirming that using a factory is the best (only?) way to create a generic multi-use click count listener

Tags: javascript, class

I have created the following click count factory for adding the click count to the event information already present in a regular click event. This function creates a clickCountObj to track the number of clicks, as well as a new function for catching a click event on the given element parameter and reporting it back to the listener parameter along with the click count.

Originally, I wanted to do this as a class, rather than a factory... Way back when I was working in Java, I would have done it with a façade class, so that's what I was thinking. But I've concluded that it is not possible in Javascript, because the same function you'd use to create the object would be the one called in response to the click, and I can't see a way around this.

The purpose of this question is simply to improve my understanding and using of JavaScript. Please let me know if I am wrong in my conclusion stated above, or if there are any other alternatives to doing this a better way?

```
function clickCount(element, listener) {
  let clickCountObj = {};
  clickCountObj.clickCount = 0;
  clickCountObj.clickDelay = 500;
  clickCountObj.element = element;
  clickCountObj.lastClickTime = 0;
  let clickCountListener = function (e) {
//    alert("last click time: " + clickCountObj.clickDelay);
    if ((e.timeStamp - clickCountObj.clickDelay) < clickCountObj.lastClickTime) {
      clickCountObj.clickCount = clickCountObj.clickCount + 1;
//      alert("click count up: " + clickCountObj.clickCount);
    }
    else {
      clickCountObj.clickCount = 1;
    }
    clickCountObj.lastClickTime = e.timeStamp;
    listener.call(element, clickCountObj.clickCount, e);
  };
  if (!element) throw "No element to listener to";
  element.addEventListener("click", clickCountListener);
  return clickCountListener;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure you can also use a class:

```
 class ClickCounter {
   constructor(element, onClick, delay = 500) {
     this.element = element;
     this.onClick = onClick;
     this.counter = 0;
     this.delay = delay;
     this.lastClicked = 0;

     element.addEventListener("click", () => this.click(), false);
  }

  click() {
    if(Date.now() < this.lastClicked + this.delay)
      return;
    this.lastClicked = Date.now();
    this.onClick.call(this.element, this.counter++);
  }
}

 new ClickCounter(document.body, count => {
   alert(count);
 });
```

> [is] doing this a better way?

No, not really. Using a class is not really useful here as you don't want to expose properties and you also don't need inheritance. A factory seems to be a good approach here.

Small sidenote: Instead of

```
 return clickCountListener;
```

it would make more sense to

```
 return clickCountObj;
```

as it would expose the settings and the count which might be useful.

---

*warning: unserious content below*

> Way back when I was working in Java ...

... you took over that senseless naming scheme (`clickCountObj.clickCount`). I guess you won't loose any necessary information with just `settings.count` ...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am returning the clickCountListener so that it can be removed later. But maybe the best thing might be to return both. Again thanks!

Comment: The issue with wanting to do this with a class was only so that I could add it and remove it directly, without needing to create another function/object.

Comment: @controlAltDel in that case I'd do `clickCountObj.remove = () => element.removeEventListener("click", clickCountListener);` so that one can easily `counter.remove()` without having to worry about the interbals of the handler.

Comment: Yes, excellent! That's really the solution I'm looking for :)

Comment: @controlAltDel glad to help :)