# Abstract Factory Pattern and Printing

Tags: java

Working on learning more design patterns - specifically here I'm working on the abstract factory pattern. I'm trying to output "Receipt 1 Header 1 Footer 1" all in one line, but I can only seem to output via the displayName method one at a time.  What is the best way to concatenate them? A toString method in the abstract classes? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Here are my classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractSalesReceiptFactory {
    public abstract AbstractReceipt createReceipt();
    public abstract AbstractHeader createHeader();
    public abstract AbstractFooter createFooter();


}

public abstract class AbstractReceipt {
    public abstract void displayName(AbstractReceipt a);

}

public abstract class AbstractHeader {
    public abstract void displayName(AbstractHeader a);

}

public abstract class AbstractFooter {
    public abstract void displayName(AbstractFooter a);

}

public class ConcreteReceipt1 extends AbstractSalesReceiptFactory{

    public AbstractReceipt createReceipt() {
        return new Receipt1();
    }
    public AbstractHeader createHeader() {
        return new Header1();
    }


    public AbstractFooter createFooter() {
        return new Footer1();
    }

    private ConcreteReceipt1() {}

    public String displayName() {
        return "Receipt1";
    }

    private static ConcreteReceipt1 instance = null;

    public static ConcreteReceipt1 getInstance() {
        instance = new ConcreteReceipt1();
        return instance;
    }

}

public class ConcreteReceipt2 extends AbstractSalesReceiptFactory{

    public AbstractReceipt createReceipt() {
        return new Receipt1();
    }

    public AbstractHeader createHeader() {
        return new Header1();
    }


    public AbstractFooter createFooter() {
        return new Footer1();
    }

    private ConcreteReceipt2() {
    }

    public String displayName() {
        return "Receipt2";
    }
    private static ConcreteReceipt2 instance = null;

    public static ConcreteReceipt2 getInstance() {
        instance = new ConcreteReceipt2();
        return instance;
    }


}

public class Footer1 extends AbstractFooter{
    public void displayName(AbstractFooter a) {
        System.out.println("Footer 1");
    }
}

public class Footer2 extends AbstractFooter{
    public void displayName(AbstractFooter a) {
        System.out.println("Footer 2");
    }
}

public class Header1 extends AbstractHeader{
    public void displayName(AbstractHeader a) {
        System.out.println("Header 1");
    }

}

public class Header2 extends AbstractHeader{
    public void displayName(AbstractHeader a) {
        System.out.println("Header 2");
    }

}

public class Receipt1 extends AbstractReceipt{
    public void displayName(AbstractReceipt a) {
        System.out.println("Receipt 1");
    }

}

public class Receipt2 extends AbstractReceipt{
    public void displayName(AbstractReceipt a) {
        System.out.println("Receipt 2");
    }

}
```

my main class:

```
public class Client {

    private static AbstractReceipt ar;
    private static AbstractHeader ah;
    private static AbstractFooter af;

    public Client(AbstractSalesReceiptFactory factory) {
        ar = factory.createReceipt();
        ah = factory.createHeader();
        af = factory.createFooter();
    }

    public void run() {
        ar.displayName(ar);
        ah.displayName(ah);
        af.displayName(af);
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        AbstractSalesReceiptFactory receipt1 = ConcreteReceipt1.getInstance();

        Client c1 = new Client(receipt1);
        c1.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Examples of Factory pattern that I've used for real things: 1. Double click listener: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52615443/confirming-that-using-a-factory-is-the-best-only-way-to-create-a-generic-mult 2. ServerSocketEx: handle the ServerSocket plumbing, and create Handlers for new sockets via factory: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/ServerSocketEx.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The absolute easiest thing you could do would be to change `System.out.println` to `System.out.print` in your existing `displayName` method implementations.
2. You could also override the `toString` method, but you may want to leave `toString` as it is and use `displayName`.
3. Another simple way to get the output you desire would be to first update the signature of `displayName` in your abstract classes so it returns `String` instead of `void` (and takes no arguments).  For example,

```java
    public abstract class AbstractReceipt {
        public abstract String displayName();
    }
```

Then update the implementations in all of your concrete classes to return the desired display name instead of printing directly.

```java
    public class Receipt1 extends AbstractReceipt{
        public String displayName() {
            return "Receipt 1";
        }
    }
```

Finally, update `run` method to perform the `System.out.println`.

```java
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(
            String.format( "%s %s %s", ar.displayName(), ah.displayName(),  af.displayName() )
        );
    }
```

However, your request is more related to Java I/O and not design patterns.  You are simply using the console output to provide dead-simple verification of your pattern implementation.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to upvote you, so: Thank you! String format was what I was looking for. I had changed the return types to string form void, but couldn't print calls to the displayName method. This fixed it. Cheers.